# Working with jQuery append for select box using AJAX, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to append the select box value to the jQuery click. In other words, when Add button is clicked it should display the next row with a select box (that is coming from database) and a text box to enter the percentage.

The below code on clicking the add button brings a new select box and a text box, but the select box value is empty.

I know that while calling this line my syntax is wrong.

```
    $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control input-md'>"+ (selectClone) +"</select></td><td><input name='percent"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Percent' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");
```

Full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Author Page</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
    var selectClone = $('select:first').clone(true); 
    // i have problem with the below line. I want to append the select box value here
    $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control input-md'>"+ (selectClone) +"</select></td><td><input name='percent"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Percent' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
    i++; 
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("book_author") or die(mysql_error());
    $rsAuth=mysql_query("select author_id,author_name from authors");
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="process_author_values.php">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
    <tr >
    <th class="text-center">
    #
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
    Book Name
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
    Percentage
    </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id='addr0'>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
    <td id="abc">
    <select class="form-control" id="abc" name="name0[]">
    <option value="0">Select an Author</option>
    <?php while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($rsAuth)){?>
    <option value="<?php  echo $row2['author_id'];?>"><?php echo $row2['author_name']; ?> </option>
    <?php  }?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name='percent0'  placeholder='Percent' class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Author</a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `selectClone.html()` will work. Here is the full line :

```
 $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control input-md'>"+ selectClone.html() +"</select></td><td><input name='percent"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Percent' class='form-control input-md'/></td>");
```

Comment: yup.. this worked. thanks a ton. BTW - who down-voted my question ;(